# Create a function pointer, which takes a generic argument, as a generic argument in a void function

Tags: c++

I have a problem to define a generic function that should work as follow:
The function should take an generic reference and a function pointer as arguments:

```
template <typename T>
void funct(T& a, void (*funcptr)(T&))
{
funcptr(a);
}

template <typename type>
void div(type& x){
x=x/2;
}

int main(){
int a=5; 
double b=5.0; 
funct<int>(a,div);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner i can't see whats wrong, can somebody help me?
thanks

Comment: This is C++. Why on Earth do this? Instead you could just declare your function like this: `template<class T, class Fun> void funct(T& a, const Fun &fun) { fun(a); }`

Comment: I don't see what's wrong either. What errors are you getting?

Comment: ./funcptr.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./funcptr.cpp: line 5: `template <typename T>'

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Your code does compile without error with newest Clang, GCC and MSVC. Are you using a compiler or doing this in your mind? :D

Comment: i wrote g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: Even so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4979088e51072bf

Comment: ohh.. really i didn't know that will work :-S...you see i'm a beginner. Actually i like to write a program, that integrate different function but i see, i did it way to complicated :D